# How to check url is working in Batch

Tags: batch-file, url, curl

I'm trying to check URL status using bat file

```
    <# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "URL=http://l:8080/LevelTwoChargerStartTransaction?chgStationRef=T0001&rfId=0.1.0.255.0.0.0.0."
powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"

goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid chimera #>

$request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($env:URL)
echo $request
$response = $request.GetResponse()
echo $response
$stream = $response.GetResponseStream()
echo $stream
$reader = new-object IO.StreamReader($stream)
echo $reader
[void]$reader.ReadToEnd()
```

and i need to get status of the URL how can i do this using batch-file or any other way to do this?

Comment: You said the batch file is working, then what's your question?

Comment: this is using Net.WebRequest class how can i do this using batch file

Comment: There are no methods... Use Powershell(like you did) or VBS.